programming error with pyodbc 42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "***";\nErro
I want to parse data from xml but when I want to insert this data to database sql via  db_cursor.execute I got error because I have some data with single and double quotation mark in one column:
import re
import os
import pyodbc
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
login_db = '\*\*\*\*\*'
passwd_db ='\*\*\*\*\*\*\*'
db_str = ("Driver={PostgreSQL UNICODE(x64)};"
"Server=\*\*\*\*\*\*\*;"
"Port=5432;"
"Database=inventory_UAT;"
"Uid=%s;"
"Pwd=%s") % (login_db, passwd_db)
db_cnxn = pyodbc.connect(db_str,autocommit=True)
db_cnxn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='utf-8')
db_cnxn.setencoding(encoding='utf-8')
db_cursor = db_cnxn.cursor()
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree1 = ET.parse(r"C:\\Mine\\diverts.xml")
root1 = tree1.getroot()
for div in root1.findall('{urn:activemq:core}divert'):
source = div.find('{urn:activemq:core}address').text
target = div.find('{urn:activemq:core}forwarding-address').text
name = div.attrib\['name'\]
filtr = ""
for i in div.findall('{urn:activemq:core}filter'):
filtr = i.attrib\['string'\]
qry = (("""INSERT INTO inventory.artemis_divert_inventory
(divert_name,from_address,to_address,filter,instance_type,last_update)
VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','CORP-UAT',NOW());""")
%(name, source, target, filtr))  
\# print(qry)
db_cursor.execute(qry)

This is the error:
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42601', '[42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "KondorSDEvent_uat1";\nError while executing the query (1) (SQLExecDirectW)')
let me add some of these data in filtr column:
_AMQ_ORIG_ADDRESS is null and (MessageType='CommodityReset' or (MessageType='Product' and ProductTy
pe='Commodity'
Publisher IN ('KondorSDEvent_uat1','AdstisSDEvent_uat1')
I dont know how to solve this problem at all

Please edit your question and show the complete text of the SQL statement and associated parameter values.

Don't use %-formatting like qry % values use parameter substitution like qry, values as described in the linked duplicate.  This will handle the quoting correctly.
